# Detect if a hook in a module is executed by Cron or UI in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have implemented `hook_node_update` in a module. I want to do some programming calculations based on if this hook is called by Drupal UI or by Drupal Cron. How can I detect this?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement `hook_cron_queue_info()` and set a static variable there that your update hook later checks.

```
function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  $cron_running = &drupal_static('mymodule_cron_running');
  $cron_running = TRUE;
  return array();
}

function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  $cron_running = &drupal_static('mymodule_cron_running');
  if ($cron_running) {
    // Custom logic.
  }
}
```